# How to calculate overlap time between 2 time range with Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a car that was installed GPS device, and i have download the moving time data like this

> Time Start = 10:42
> Time End = 11:15

my question, how can i calculate how long the car was moving in specific time range between :

1. 10:00 clock to 10:59 clock = ? minutes
2. 11:00 clock to 11:59 clock = ? minutes

oh course in this case the answer is very simple

1. 10:00 clock to 10:59 clock = 18 minutes moving
2. 11:00 clock to 11:59 clock = 15 minutes moving

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post a data example and how is your Excel display? Also, post the formulas you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do it is:

```
=(B5>=$A$2)*(B5<=$B$2)*(B5-$A$2) + (A5<=$B$2)*(A5>=$A$2)*($B$2-A5)
```

or alternatively in a more readable way:

```
=IF(AND(B5>=$A$2,B5<=$B$2),B5-$A$2) + IF(AND(A5<=$B$2,A5>=$A$2),($B$2-A5))
```

where **A2** is the Time Start (10:42) and **B2** is the Time End (11:15) and
**A5** is 10:00 and **B5** is 11:00.

Like this:

[image]